# Is there a way to detect if a JavaScript method is interrupted by GC?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I am trying to profile a JavaScript function which normally takes under 1ms to execute. But in some very rare scenarios, it can take as high as a few hundred milliseconds to finish executing, and I suspect that it's due to GC interrupting the execution of the method.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to tell the browser to not run GC while a particular function is executing (can be browser specific).
2. Can I detect when a GC event has happened.

For the last question, I was thinking of using the new `performance.memory` object:

```
var startHeap = performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize
// execute JS method here
if (performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize < startHeap) {
    //GC event
}
```

The issue with this method is that, at least in Chrome, the used heap value is terribly inaccurate. It is rounded to hundredths of kilobytes, and won't change if a GC event has executed.

Comment: What the hell are you writing that few hundred millis is not fast enough and you have to dive into internals?

Comment: It's a handler on mutation events. So each time that a DOM attribute is modified or a new element is inserted, the method is executed and needs to be very very fast.

Comment: @freakish Few hundred msecs are few 1/10 secs ... It's a long time in some situations, when "few" gets near 5 ... Think about animations for example.

Comment: It's not. Even 1sec lag is not a big deal usually, seriously. Unless you are writing a FPS online.

Comment: "hundredths of kilobytes" equals out to 10 bytes: how much more precise does it need to be? but in practical terms, you can just ignore the time it takes, nothing else is getting ahead or behind during the pause, so it doesn't matter. also, don't expect mutations to always report in the correct order: they are async events and need to be treated as such if you want it to work 100% of the time...